# Returning unmatched substrings

Tags: substring, matching

I want to compare adress list (`B`) to a list of people including adressess (`A`). The code owerwrites the values so that A including irrelevant information is printed.

How do I modify it in order for it to print the `B` values that are matched?

Or, even better: is it possible to get an output of `B` values not contained in any `A`?

```py
A = ["<hi>", "12you","good"]
B = ["hi", "you", "good", "luck"]
C = [x for x in A if any(b in x for b in B)]

print(C)
```

desired output: `'hi', 'you', 'good'`
more desired output: `'luck'`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry mister Bot. This is the entire code I am using. Should I also post the output?

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve the first task by regex search and extraction of the group.  The second one then just reduces to subtracting the found adresses from the list of available ones.

```py
>>> addresses = re.compile("|".join(f"({b})" for b in B))
>>> addresses.pattern
'(hi)|(you)|(good)|(luck)'

>>> [m.group(0) for a in A if (m := addresses.search(a))]
['hi', 'you', 'good']

>>> set(B).difference([m.group(0) for a in A if (m := addresses.search(a))])
{'luck'}
```